# AngularJS MongoDB - Date type

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, date, filter

What can I do to compare these different Date-Types for my filter????

MongDB:

```
2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z
```

Datepicker:

```
Wed Apr 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

---

I have a MEAN Stack and write Data from a form into a MongoDB Database.
My database entry looks like this:

dt for Date

[image]

I use UI-Bootstrap Datepicker to pick the date and save it in this format:

```
2015-03-31T22:00:00.000Z
```

Now I have two other Datepickers to set a range and filter them.
But when I choose a date in the Datepickers the format change to:

```
Wed Apr 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

and I can't compare these two data in my Filter:

```
angular.module('reklaApp')
 .filter('dateFilter', function () {
    return function (items, fromDate, toDate) {

    var filtered = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        var item = items[i];

        if (item.dt > fromDate && item.dt < toDate){
            filtered.push(item);
        }
    }

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create javascript native `Date` objects and compare them:

```
var a = new Date("2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z")
var b = new Date("Wed Apr 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)")

console.log(a > b) // -> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse and convert both date formats to a date instance. Probably, since you are already using a datepicker, the later dates i.e. from & end dates must be a date instance. So the only thing you have to do is to parse the MongoDB date string.